# Modify an Specific instance of class

Tags: vb.net

Lets suppose i have a class like so:

```
Public Class Car

Private _id As Integer

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Public Property ID As Integer
    Get
        Return _id
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _id = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

and i have a button that does the following:

```
   Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Stuff As New Car
    'Other code..

End Sub
```

and i press the button like 10 times...

How can i modify an specific instance of this class (like, the one created when i clicked the button for the third time) to modify its properties?

Comment: Are you doing something with that `Car` object each time? Or else it's just local to that handler func.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Stuff` instance only exists inside the Button click event.  To give it larger/longer `Scope` you need to declare it elsewhere:

```
Dim Stuff As Car            ' what it is

Private Sub Button2_Click(...
  Stuff = New Car     ' actual instancing/creation of Stuff of Type Car
  'Other code..

End Sub
```

To make multiples for every click, you need some sort of collection to store them

```
Dim Cars As New List(Of Car)         ' many other collections will work
Dim CarItem As Car                   ' car instances to put in it

Private Sub Button2_Click(... 
  CarItem = New Car     ' instance of Type Car

  Cars.Add(CarItem)

End Sub
```

Now, to do something to the third car you made, reference Cars(3):

```
Cars(3).Make = "Kia"
Cars(3).Color = "Blue"
```